# Flex 4 - How to draw or place a border around both the checkbox and label portion of the CheckBox

Tags: apache-flex, checkbox, flex4, border

I have been doing much research on this - including creating a custom skin but cannot seem to be able to do it.  I just want to have one border around both the checkbox and label. I also want a background color which I did manage to via opaqueBackground property (setting it via AS3).  Just can't seem to find the key to have a border as well.  Any help is appreciated.  I need the same for radio buttons as well.

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track by creating a custom skin.  Just copy the default CheckBoxSkin and add a Rect at the top level so it gets drawn first (below where the states are declared and before the first Group):

```
<s:Rect left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">
    <s:stroke>
        <s:SolidColorStroke color="#ff0000"/>
    </s:stroke>
</s:Rect>
```

Then set your new skin as the checkbox skin, either in CSS or directly on the specific checkbox via its skinClass.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Wow - that was too easy - thanks very much!!!  I guess if I wanted to make the border thicker I would add something into the skin also.  I will give that a try also.  Again - thank you.  I have learned a great deal searching the internet for Flex help.  I have 8 books and a bunch of bookmarks.  If you know any good sites or books please let me know.  This is FUN!